# passing an array for user-defined function fitting in python

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit a user-defined function with scipy.optimize.curve_fit function, and run into this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

The error is related to a line of code which used a min() function, and I realized that this problem is not limited to min() function. For example, given a simple function:

```
def func2(x,a,b):
    m=2
    if x>5:
        return(m*a*b)
    else:
        return(x*a*b)
```

I can reproduce the same error code if I pass an array to the function:

```
x1=np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
func2(x1,1,1)
```

Apparently, when x1 is passed to the function, it takes the whole list, and causes the comparison by '>' a ValueError since it expects a real value to be compared to number 5 in my example.

To bypass this problem, the user-defined function can be run error-free as a list comprehension:

```
[func2(i,1,1) for i in x1]
```

it gives the expected output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

My problem is that I cannot use this list comprehension in the curve_fit function. My independent and dependent values have to be passed as arrays, and I have to use a comparison line (I used a min() function, to the same effect as my example code here) in my function.

Any insight on this particular problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where, the condition, followed by what to return if true, and what to return if false:

```
def func2(x,a,b):
    m=2
    return np.where(x>5,m*a*b,x*a*b)
```

Comment: Thanks. I incorporated the np.where function into the curve_fit, and worked if I pass an array as input. The only problem is that the function produces a TypeError if I use a number as an input. I incorporated an additional if-else loop to catch this error.